# MYSQL SELECT unique values from column where column2 = value & count how many times each unique value was found

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am looking to select and count each occurrence of column phone_number where column2 email_eddress == value.

**Example DB Tables**

Table: some_numbers

```
id | sender_email | phoner_number
1 | email@example.com | 555-555-5555
2 | email2@example.net | 666-666-6666
3 | email@example.com | 555-555-5555
4 | email@example.com | 123-456-7890
```

I am trying to select the phone_number value and the number of times each unique phone_number number was found WHERE sender_email = $email variable that is set to check an individual email address).

I can't seem to figure out how to query this in a way that I can just output something like shown below.

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT**

email@example.com | 555-555-5555 (2), 123-456-7890 (1)

email2@example.net | 666-666-6666 (1)

**My Attempt:**

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT phone_number FROM some_numbers GROUP BY sender_email");
    foreach($results as $result){
        $number = trim($result['phone_number']);

        echo $number.BR;
    }
```

Comment: just add count on the query to get the number of count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query should work:

```
select sender_email, phone_number, count(*)
from some_numbers 
group by sender_email, phone_number;
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d3f0/3/0)**.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried something similar but it was throwing bad syntax error so I scrapped it since I couldn't see any obvious syntax issues it at the time, this is working great.